# How to add the support for structured annotations to the EF Core SqlServer target builder?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, annotations, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

It is easy to add plain string annotations to the EF model with `HasAnnotation` method that accept `object` type of argument, but trying to add structured annotations you will get errors on build migration:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasAnnotation($"{GetType().FullName}.Constraint3", new ValueTuple<string,string>( "aaa", "bbb" ));

The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type 'System.ValueTuple`2[System.String,System.String]'. Configure your services to use one that can.

        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasAnnotation($"{GetType().FullName}.Constraint2", new[] { "aaa", "bbb" });

The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type 'System.String[]'. Configure your services to use one that can.
```

Do we have a way to inject a method to the `target builder` that would help to serialize structured annotations?

Why I would need it? Just trying to collect all database meta in one place. And meta is usually structured info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand (there is not much if any at all information about that), the idea is to use simple name / value pairs, where the values are primitive types (`string`, `int`, `decimal`, `DateTime` etc. plus `enum`s) and names form the structure. All EF Core annotations follow that principle. For instance, Name: `"SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy"` Type: `SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy` etc.

Probably the easiest is to simply follow that convention. But anyway, the responsible service is [`ICSharpHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.icsharphelper?view=efcore-2.0) - [`UnknownLiteral`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.icsharphelper.unknownliteral?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Design_ICSharpHelper_UnknownLiteral_System_Object_) method. And the default implementation is in [`CSharpHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.internal.csharphelper?view=efcore-2.0) class.

So you can derive from it, override the `UnknownLiteral` method and do your own (pre)processing there:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal;

public class MyCSharpHelper : CSharpHelper
{
    public override string UnknownLiteral(object value)
    {
        // Preprocess the value here...
        return base.UnknownLiteral(value);
    }
}
```

then replace the standard service with yours:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ICSharpHelper, MyCSharpHelper>();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I was composing question I had tryed POCO with the same result (error)... But now I will experiment little bit more with it.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried it before posting and it worked. With your first sample, the code was something like `if (value is ValueTuple<string, string> vt) return $"new ValueTuple<string, string>({Literal(vt.Item1)}, {Literal(vt.Item2)})";` And it generated correct `HasAnnotation` in migration `designer.cs` file. Make sure your service is called by putting temporarily `throw new Exception("Blah");` at the beginning of the overridden method. Tested with EFC 2.0.1 if that matters.

Comment: yep this works and very surprised way (directly insert the text to migration sources)... I got a great feeling of "wizard of liquid code". thank you very much. at least migrations in ef core done flexible way (I deeply dissatisfied with EF core logging particularly and EF core DI "container only" manner generally).

Comment: Ivan, may be I can ask you to tell your ideas on those quesions (first is continuation of attempts to reuse EF COre metamodel ): 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242973/ef-core-how-to-build-model-without-context-how-to-get-the-same-conventionset-u 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744989/how-to-update-the-entity-before-delete-on-savecontext

Comment: Hi @Roman, Sure, I will when have some time. But note that I'm not participating in EF Core development, so all my posts are based on documentation, experimenting and exploring the source code :)

Comment: You are right I had a hope that you are insider. But you are so deep in it that should write a book. Or a boilerplate of high configurable EF usage (per-context-logging + model-extension + standard sql/dml modification)... I have first only ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680174/entity-framework-core-log-queries-for-a-single-db-context-instance/47490737#47490737 ), and a half of second (after your help).